# ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized title for custom intent: 'Configuration' not found for locale: de_DE

Tags: ios, xcode, widget, app-store-connect, siri

I uploaded my App to AppStore connect (using Xcode 12 Beta 6) and received a Mail with this warning. The App is available in TestFlight.
My App uses a Widget with an AppGroup, but I'm not using Siri (not selected from Capability).
I already dissected "Configurable in Shortcuts" as wells as "Suggestions" in the Intents.intetdefinition from Xcode.
I already search but didn't found a solution working for me.
I found one answer that suggested to add AppIntentVocabulary.plist to the project. I've never worked with that file and don't know how to use it.

Has anyone an Idea what I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: Try uploading using xCode 11.7

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm facing a similar issue with an app with a widget target submitted with Xcode 12.0 GM.

Comment: @vrutberg my problem was that I localised my WidgetView.intentdefinition file with English as well as with German. Removed the german localization and now it's working.

Comment: Alright, thanks for getting back to me. My problem was that I had actually forgotten to fill in the description. Guess I should have read the error message more carefully before I went to StackOverflow. 

Answer (score 30):

Filling in the description worked for me.

**Intent description**

[image]

Comment: Hi! Where's this option located? Really struggle to find it 

Comment: Found it! This option located in your Extension, in *.intentdefinition file. In Xcode look for the file in your extension folder with an icon looking like a circle with two crossing lines inside.

Comment: Where do you localize\write the string corresponding to that description? I have a strings file in my locale but I"m still getting warned on submission!

Does the name of the .strings file have to match the Custom Intents name on the left ("SelectLocation") or the Title on the right ("Select Location")?

Comment: Added to what Mike Keskinov said, double-click the file located in Extension folder, and you will see window like the screenshot posted by op

Answer (score 3):

My app has both a **SiriKit / Intents Extension** (no Siri shortcuts) and a **Widget Extension**. Even though the warning was about "Invalid Siri Support", it actually targeted the widget's `.intentdefinition` file (which explicitly had none of the siri options enabled).

Setting its proper localization silenced the warning, although this should not have been necessary since the app only has one language (meaning the base localization is not English).

Interestingly this also compelled the App Review Team to reject the app, since "they could not find any Siri shortcuts". Explaining that there are no Siri shortcuts was futile.